# Web Service Large Volume Of Calls On Amazon EC2

Tags: web-services, iis, amazon-web-services

I am new to using web services but we have built a simple web service hosted in IIS on an Amazon EC2 instance with an Amazon RDS hosted database server, this all works fine as a prototype for our mobile application.

The next stage s to look at scale and I need to know how we can have a cluster of instances handling the web service calls as we expect to have a high number of calls to the web service and need to scale the number of instances handling the calls.

I am pretty new to this so at the moment I see we use an IP address in the call to the web service which implies its directed at a specific server> how do we build an architecture on Amazon where the request from the mobile device can be handled by one of a number of servers and in which we can scale the capacity to handle more web service calls by just adding more servers on Amazon

Thanks for any help

Steve

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use load balancing, that conveniently AWS also offers:

http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/

> Elastic Load Balancing automatically distributes incoming application traffic across multiple Amazon EC2 instances. It enables you to achieve even greater fault tolerance in your applications, seamlessly providing the amount of load balancing capacity needed in response to incoming application traffic. Elastic Load Balancing detects unhealthy instances within a pool and automatically reroutes traffic to healthy instances until the unhealthy instances have been restored. Customers can enable Elastic Load Balancing within a single Availability Zone or across multiple zones for even more consistent application performance.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Elastic Load Balancing](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/), you'll want to have an [Amazon Machine Image](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AMIs.html) created, so you can launch instances on-demand without having to do manual configuration on each instance you launch.  The EC2 documentation describes that process.

There's also [Auto Scaling](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-auto-scaling-elb.html), which lets you set specific metrics to watch and automatically provision more instances.  I believe it's throttled, so you don't have to worry about creating way too many, assuming you set reasonable thresholds at which to start and stop launching more instances.

Last (for a simple overview), you'll want to consider being in multiple [availability zones](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/CHAP_Glossary.html) so you're resilient to any potential outages.  They aren't frequent, but they do happen.  There's no guarantee you'll be available if you're only in one AZ.